How to work with copy editors when the document is in TeX?
I have a big book that is ready for a copy editor. The problem is, my document is not in a single file, and it has lots of custom TeX macros mixed in.
As I understand it, most copy editors will open a single Word file in Google Docs or Microsoft Word, edit it themselves with "show changes" enabled, and send it back. They typically look at improving the mechanics, style, and prose, so aren't so concerned I think about where things are on a page. Converting the Chicago-style footnotes from my TeX macros to Word document footnote would take months.
First, TeX code is mixed throughout. While writing my book, I made a significant attempt to separate my writing from the code. For instance, I have files like chapter1.tex, chapter2.tex that are 95% just the words. However, there was no escaping marking the text with citations, special punctuation marks, etc.
Second, the content is split across folders and files. Larges parts of the book are found in nearly a hundred smaller .tex files. Though this made the content easier on the writer to churn out content, its not easy for an outsider to navigate, least of which when sometimes a paragraph might draw upon content for a bulleted list from an outside, generated file.
The only way to really "see" the document and read the text linearly is to read the PDF, but that doesn't seem to match up with the process of opening a document, editing it, and sending it back with changes applied.
Can copy editors work from a PDF? How do other LaTeX users handle working with a copy editor? What is the best way to work with a copy editor when you've used TeX/LaTeX?

Depending on the purpose (just checkreading to layout control) pdf can be imported in Word. Here‘s an article from 2019, mentioning some drawbacks at that time: https://smallbusiness.chron.com/copy-scanned-document-microsoft-word-54580.html . Did you contact your publisher on this?

For the LaTeX companion copy editing was done by sending a pdf to the editor and they added comments. The test corrections should be done before fine tuning the page layout so the editor must ignore misplaced floats and large white space from bad page breaking.

Comments can easily be made in PDF using Acrobat.  I've done this for many years with technical material, including equations, etc. Word, on the other hand, has the ability to do direct edits and accept/reject easily.  But it's hopeless for equations.

For my thesis, some of the reviewers did not have LaTeX. I had sent them a pdf, they annotated it with mac os preview with deletions and suggestions marked in red. And general comments in blue. Though not a TeX solution or straightforward, it worked for me.

For complex documents with many files, consider creating a master "compiled" TeX file that incorporates all chapters for easier navigation during editing, even if the actual editing happens in another format.

Publishers have “Instructions for authors” which state what format they are willing to accept. Some are happy with (La)TeX, like Springer or Elsevier. Others can handle only Word, and the worst do not even do copy-editing, they expect a camera-ready pdf-file which they have printed and that's it. All they do for you is getting an ISBN.
My books are published by Springer, and there TeX is welcome. When I first published there some 20 years ago, the copy editor apparently was not TeX-aware and very impressed when after some reordering of pages (to get colour printed pages together, at that time it made printing cheaper) he asked me to redo the index and I answered: “Just run makeindex, it will do that chore automatically”.

I've done a handful, not many, of textbooks entirely in LaTeX with the same small inhouse team, and in our experience, we feel we have to view and treat copyediting and typesetting as two different and separate processes.
In my case, as the only one who understands how to dabble with LaTeX codes on the team, I would typically wait for the textual "deep reading" edits that our copyediting team preferred to do in Google Docs (we are an almost-remote team). The setter is also often involved in this line, as some special formatting or design considerations often needed to be cleared with the copyeditors, which sometimes needed to be passed on to the author. The "mostly done" file is then sent to the setter, who transforms the copy into a half-done internal PDF draft, which is then further treated by the copyeditors and authors to be commented on in the Google Drive. At this phase, the setter would often only fix a handful of typos, formatting changes, and final cleanups.
Also, comments and annotations on PDFs are easily made with most contemporary PDF viewers and are listed so that the setter can jump from note to note.

Was the Google Doc of the pdf?  What does a "setter" do?  Is this basically "several people mark up the pdf, and then someone who knows TeX (only me) actually makes the changes"?

Sorry for the unfamiliar terms, I don't live in the English-speaking area. The Google Docs part is where the original finished copies (or the manuscripts as we call them) done by the author are mainly sculpted and thrown back and forth from the author to us and vice versa, riddled with comments and revisions. Since many people are familiar with Word, we accept plain docx manuscripts with minimal formatting. The type-"setter" is someone who does the LaTeX part (in this case, me). In short, copies are done separatedly from the later stages, which is the part when the contents actually laid out.
